# clojure pr-str cutting off lists > 100 items

Tags: clojure

I am trying to serialize some lists in clojure using pr-str, but any list with over 100 elements is getting cut off. Example:

```
(pr-str (repeat 200 [2]))
```

yields

```
"([2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] [2] ...)"
```

Comment: Just tried it with 1.5.1 clojure in ordinary REPL and in Lein REPL, I got all 200 elements.. what version of clojure and what REPL do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you have `*print-length*` bound to 100. To lift the limit, reset it to `nil`:

```
(set! *print-length* nil)
```

As for where it could be bound / set in the first place, that depends on your setup. For Leiningen, both user-level and project-level settings are relevant (so have a look in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` and in `project.clj`).

Comment: You were right about *print-length*. Unfortunately, I can't figure out where it's getting set; it's not in my project.clj or profiles.clj...

Comment: Emacs Live was setting *print-length* deep inside its nrepl config files. Really annoying.