# write large data structures as EDN to disk in clojure

Tags: clojure, edn

What is the most idiomatic way to write a data structure to disk in Clojure, so I can read it back with edn/read? I tried the following, as recommended in the [Clojure cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/04_local-io/4-14_read-write-clojure-data-structures.asciidoc):

```
(with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer "data.clj")]
  (binding [*out* w]
    (pr large-data-structure)))
```

However, this will only write the first 100 items, followed by "...". I tried `(prn (doall large-data-structure))` as well, yielding the same result.

I've managed to do it by writing line by line with `(doseq [i large-data-structure] (pr i))`, but then I have to manually add the parens at the beginning and end of the sequence to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the number of items in a collection that are printed via [*print-length*](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/%2Aprint-length%2A)

<strike>Consider using [spit](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/spit) instead of manually opening the writer and [pr-str](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pr-str) instead of manually binding to `*out*`.</strike>

```
(binding [*print-length* false]
  (spit "data.clj" (pr-str large-data-structure))
```

Edit from comment:

```
(with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer "data.clj")]
  (binding [*print-length* false
            *out* w]
    (pr large-data-structure)))
```

**Note**: `*print-length*` has a root binding of `nil` so you should not need to bind it in the example above. I would check the current binding at the time of your original `pr` call.

Comment: Using `(pr-str)` is a bad idea for a large data structure; it will print it to a string in memory, which may take more memory than the original structure. I would simply add the `*print-length*` nil binding to the binding vector in OP's code.

Comment: My `*print-length*` was set to 100. The culprit seems to be emacs live. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300594/clojure-pr-str-cutting-off-lists-100-items